# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface while trying to pass a JSON object to a java process

Tags: java, json, subprocess, python-3.4

I am using Python's subprocess to call a Java program within Python. The input/output to the Java program is JSON object.

Here is my code, the variable `args` is basically list of arguments that the program takes in.

```
json_object = json.dumps([{"foo" :1, "bar": 2}])
p = subprocess.Popen(args,executable="/usr/bin/java",stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout =subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(json_object)
p.stdin.close()
out = json.load(p.stdout)
```

However, I am having the error: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

I am using Python 3.4. I tried to convert the `json_object` into bytes but that is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write a Unicode string to a subprocess. Either encode the string first, or use `universal_newlines=True` to open the pipe in Unicode mode (with newline translation included) to have Unicode strings auto-encoded to the *standard* locale for your system.

From the [`subprocess` module FAQ section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If *universal_newlines* is `False` the file objects *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* will be opened as **binary streams**, and no line ending conversion is done.
>
> If *universal_newlines* is `True`, these file objects will be opened as text streams in *universal newlines* mode using the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`. For *stdin*, line ending characters `'\n'` in the input will be converted to the default line separator `os.linesep`. For *stdout* and *stderr*, all line endings in the output will be converted to `'\n'`. For more information see the documentation of the `io.TextIOWrapper` class when the *newline* argument to its constructor is `None`.

For JSON data, I'd just encode to UTF-8 here; use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) rather than write yourself though, as this'll handle waiting for data better. You'll also need to *decode* the JSON data again. Assuming your subprocess also returns UTF-8 encoded JSON that'd look like this:

```
out_raw = p.communicate(json_object.encode('utf8'))[0]
out = json.loads(out_raw.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Now, I get the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'` because out_raw is assigned the value returned by the program plus some information from the prompt. Here is what it looks like: (b'XXX XXX json_object XXX XXX). The XXX XXX is message grabbed from the prompt. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @user2161903 yes, sorry about that. You get a tuple of stdout and stderr; corrected by adding `[0]` to select just the first.

Comment: Right, I actually avoided the command line prompt. Thanks again.